# I cannot use wget or pip without encountering connection errors after following tutorial

Tags: raspbian, access-point, dns, pip, hostapd

I followed these access point **instructions** (lines of commands and file edits) <strike>tutorial</strike>, and now whenever I use wget or pip, connection errors are thrown.

These were the instructions I followed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install hostapd
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq 
sudo systemctl stop hostapd
sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq
```

I make an edit to `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

Towards the end of the file I add these lines

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=<pi's ip address>/24
denyinterfaces eth0
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

I configure the DHCP server

First I make a copy:

```
sudo mv /etc/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig
sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

then I make an edit:

```
interface=wlan0
  dhcp-range=192.168.0.11,192.168.0.30,255.255.255.0,24h
```

Configure the access point software:

```
sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf


interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ssid=myNETWORK
wpa_passphrase=myPASSWORD
```

Show the locatin of the configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/default/hostapd
```

Uncomment this line:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Setup port forwarding:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Uncomment this line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Add a new iptables rule

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Save the rule:

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

Load the rule on boot:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

Enable internet connection (build a bridge):

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
sudo brctl addbr br0
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
```

Edit the interfaces file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
```

So now whenever I try and install any python modules or download anything, connection errors are generated. This is an example:

```
connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection...')
```

I also added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf`. That did not solve my problem.
I also tried turning off `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`. Nothing changes.

Edit: Removed link to tutorial and added a list of instructions that I followed.

Edit 2: It should also be noted that this access point does work, the raspberry pi zero that connects to this access point does in fact have an internet connection and I can ssh into it from a different computer.

Comment: We cannot follow and "repair"all tutorials out there on the web to create an access point. Start again with a fresh flashed *Raspberry Pi OS Lite* based on Buster and follow the official tutorials [Wireless connectivity](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/). If you get problems then, please ask again. You may also have a look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) and [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).

Comment: Please don't just [state](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2197/33476) you followed a tutorial: include commands needed to reproduce the error, the exact error message and the expected behaviour, if it cannot be trivially deduced from the commands.

Comment: Post fixed. I removed the link to the tutorial and added the instructions.

Comment: Also, recommending a clean install of an operating system is not an ideal solution.

Comment: With that said, I will most likely need to do that.

Comment: I have a suspicion that I cannot perform an HTTPS connections because I essentially turned my raspberry pi into a router, and I believe that would interfere with HTTP/HTTPS